# Getting Current Time/Date - Saving To SQL Database

Tags: php, sql, date, time

I have an application that posts to an PHP script, I want the PHP script to basically grab the current time and date, and insert it into my SQL database.

I'm currently doing this by using '`$time()`' within PHP, and then passing that into my SQL DB. In order to retrieve the time and date back, I use '`gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", $time);`'.

I have a few questions though:

- When I test this, the time it saves is an hour behind, so how do I apply different time zones? (I'm currently London/England) - but that might not be the case for the user who use this application.
- Where is PHP retrieving the time from? Is it local? From the server?
- Within my SQL, what should I set the data type to be? Timestamp? Currently, I've set it to varchar - but with all these different date and time types, I'm not so sure? (Date, Datetime, Time, Timestamp).

This PHP is called every time the user opens the application, so I want to be able to see: 'ah, so I see this user opened the application up at 21:20 on Wednesday the 14th'.

I'm sorry if its a noob question, but theres so many time and date classes and functions for both PHP and SQL that my brain has over loaded!

Comment: "Where is PHP retrieving the time from?" It retrieves it from the machine, upon which php is executed.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, PHP time gets it's time from the server it's running on.

But if you really want the time a record was inserted, you should do one of the following:

1. Create a field in the table of type datetime, and set the default to:

   GETDATE()

This will set the time automatically without you having to do anything special.

1. If you need that at time of input, still use SQL:

   update [tablename] set LastUpdate=GETDATE()

Doing it this way ensures that the time is exactly when the record was set.

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP Time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function returns the EPOCH time (Seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

You can use [date_default_timezone_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) along with [strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) or [mktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to convert this to the servers local time.

You could set this via your application for the user if they're in a different timezone.

I linked the PHP manual pages for each function listed above.

Answer (score 0):

What about to create a DateTime Field on MySQL table Structure and use MySQL to grab and set the date with NOW()?. Let MySQL do most calculations, it will help you to optimize the response time of your PHP script.

Look into this example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp

Following the example of that page, but for an UPDATE:
 `UPDATE orders set OrderDate=NOW() WHERE OrderId=9999`

Answer (score 0):

```
Setting Timezone will fix the issue. I guess.

$date = date_create('2000-01-01', timezone_open('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```